# Refer to nested HTML elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some extensive **HTML** element in the following (simplified) format:

```
<div id="firstdiv" class="container">
    <ul>
        <li id="4"> <a title="ID:4">Tree</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="005"> <a title="ID:005">Leaf Tree</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="10"> <a title="ID:10">Fruit Tree</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="0050338"> <a title="ID:0050338">Apple Tree</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li id="399"> <a title="ID:399">Green Apple Tree</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="005"> <a title="ID:005">Conifer</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="10"> <a title="ID:10">Pine Tree</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>               
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to access the value of the title attributes of all a-tags inside the div-container with the id="firstdiv" on click.
I tried the following **jQuery** function but it didn't work:

```
$("#firstdiv").children("a").on('click', function () { /*some code here*/ });
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`children()` only goes one deep try `find()`

```
$("#firstdiv").on('click', function () {
    $(this).find('a').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).attr('title'))
    })
});
```

will get all `a` tags titles when the `#first_div` is clicked

```
$("#firstdiv a").on('click', function () {
    console.log($(this).attr('title'))
});
```

will get the title of the `a` tag you clicked on

Answer (score 3):

`children()` does what it says, looks at child nodes only - not descendant nodes also. For that, you need `find()`. However, you need neither in your case, just a change to your selector.

```
$('#firstdiv a')
```

As with CSS, a space in the selector denotes a child OR descendant.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only
>   travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse
>   down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren,
>   etc.) as well

So change your selector to:

`$("#firstdiv").find("a").on("click", function () {});`

This will search everything beneath #firstdiv in your DOM tree.

Answer (score 2):

Or even:

```
$('#firstdiv a').click(function(){
   ... do stuff
});
```

That will select all 'a' elements within #firstdiv

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/ApfJz/22/

```
$("#firstdiv a").on('click', function () { alert($(this).attr('title')); });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bBnRY/3/)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#firstdiv a').click(function(){
            alert($(this).attr('title'))
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#firstdiv").find("a").on('click', function () {

});
```